# Compress video while streaming using C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, video-streaming, http-compression

I'm wondering if is it possible to compress the video stream using .NET (C#).

I have a video on the web server and I want to compress and broadcast it to the client's app. The client's app will decompress that stream and then show the video.

Comment: Video files are already compressed, You can at most change the codec or bitrate of it(which would mean a great CPU load).

Comment: @L.B Videos are not compressed by definition, they just happen to have some form of compression more often than not.

Comment: @casperOne Of course. But how many times have you seen a video file with a *raw* format. I'd just wanted to write a short comment. Did you expect a whole blog about video formats,compression etc.

Comment: @L.B No, but I wanted the comment to be *correct* =)  I don't know what kind of video Tony is working with, but it's not uncommon to work with feeds of uncompressed data in real time (but you'd usually want a hardware solution then).

Comment: @casperOne I worked in that area, and even by using the HW solutions, working with uncompressed data is not common.

Comment: @casperOne I've edited the question and now it's understandable and 
"a real question". And I'd like to see the answer. Can it be reopened??

Comment: @SEARAS There's nowhere nearly enough information to answer this question.  There's no information about codecs, how the clients are connecting, etc.  It's *way* too broad.

Comment: @Tony, now it's your turn. Tell video codec name (mpeg,avi...) and streaming protocol (such as rtp://, mms://...). If you don't need this topic anymore, plz let me modify this question for my needs =)

Comment: @SEARAS If you have a question that's better, and specific to your needs, better to ask it yourself.